# Conditional avatar for WooCommerce members and normal customers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

hi there m  using [WooCommerce Memberships by SkyVerge](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) for a membership plan, m trying to make conditional avatars for users and members, when the user is a member their avatar is different and when he is not a member then different, I have two sample codes, can anyone make them conditional

```
// Custom Default Gravatar Only For Members
add_filter( 'pre_get_avatar', 'custom_gravatar', 1, 3 );
function custom_gravatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $args ) {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $uid ) ) {
        $avatar = "<img src='https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp'/>";
    }
    return $avatar;
}

// Default Gravatar For Non-Members or Users
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
    $myavatar                     = 'http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png';
    $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
    return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

Comment: Just use if else - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/#section-7

Comment: i tried this but it's not working

Comment: `$memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $user_id );`

Comment: `if ( ! empty( $memberships ) ) {
    // do something for this active member
    function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
        $myavatar                     = 'http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png';
        $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
}`

Comment: `else {
    function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
        $myavatar                     = 'https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp';
        $avatar_defaults[ $myavatar ] = 'Default Gravatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
}

add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );`

Comment: u cant else a function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
function ht1_change_avatar($args, $id_or_email) {
   $active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
    if( $active_memberships ){
        $myavatar = 'https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp';
    }else{
        $myavatar = 'https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smiley-blushing-emoji-emoticon-3.gif';
    }
    $args['url'] = $myavatar;
    return $args;
}
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'ht1_change_avatar', 100, 2);
```

```php
function ht1_change_avatar($args, $id_or_email) {
   $active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
    if( $active_memberships ){
        $myavatar = 'https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp';
    }else{
        $myavatar = 'https://buysnd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smiley-blushing-emoji-emoticon-3.gif';
    }
    $args['url'] = $myavatar;
    return $args;
}
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'ht1_change_avatar', 100, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant test it at full bcs of the membership plugin but this should work

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_avatar', 'custom_gravatar', 1, 3 );
function custom_gravatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $args ) {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    //determine if user is an active member
    if ( $uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $uid ) ) {
        $avatar = "<img src='https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp'/>";
    } 
    // if not use default 
    else {
        $avatar = "<img src='http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png'/>";
    }
    return $avatar;
}

//Change action if you need
add_action('init','user_member_avatar');
function user_member_avatar() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) return;
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    if ( $uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $uid ) ) {
        $avatar_url = esc_url('https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp');
    } else {
        $avatar_url = esc_url('http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png');
    }
    return $avatar_url;
}
```

Comment: actually i did not want <img src=''> under $avatar, can we use only image URL path instead of full HTML img tag

Comment: `add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );`

Comment: `function wpb_new_gravatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    //determine if user is an active member
    if ( $uid && wc_memberships_get_user_active_memberships( $uid ) ) {
        $myavatar = "https://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Circle_Design_Membership_Level_GOLD.webp";
    } 
    // if not use default 
    else {
        $myavatar = "http://staranddaisy.in/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/smily_icon_avatar-1.png";
    }
    $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
    return $avatar_defaults;
}`

Comment: This is by your example i dont know what u want to load. Change it as you see fit :) Also check what this filter expects - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_avatar/ - Allows the HTML for a user’s avatar to be returned early.

Comment: actually, your `function` is a working file on the website, but the thing is m using a flutter app which takes data from Rest API, so it can take only URL not HTML, which u can see in my question `// Default Gravatar For Non-Members or Users` is working fine with my app your given `function`  working only website because of `HTML` tag its not passing the value

Comment: Then u can go in the app and check if user is member or not and apply the avatar u need? Wordpress is using gravatar service so you are limited to some extend. I have added second function that you can use for your url issue but has nothing to do with the avatars. If you still wanna change the avatars keep the pre_get_avatar filter.